# How to get current location using uber api & provide functionality for selecting pickup & drop off location?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, uber-api

I am trying to integrate Uber API. How do I get the user's current location in order to set the default pickup location? Secondly, how do I add the functionality of selecting pick up & drop off location similar to Uber App? Any references which could help me in integrating the above-discussed functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I think deeplinking into the Uber app with preset parameters might be your best option here. The setPickup action is a very powerful deep linking feature which allows you to launch the Uber app and do any combination of setting pickup, drop-off, and product selection. Guides on how to use this are here: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/deep-links/introduction#notes

This includes the ability to set current location per your request: "You can set the pickup location to be the user's current location by setting pickup to my_location. With that, you don't need to provide latitude/longitude query parameters."

Comment: And how to provide destination location lat/long?

Comment: "The setPickup action is a very powerful deep linking feature which allows you to launch the Uber app and do any combination of setting pickup, drop-off, and product selection." - Please read the documentation. Thanks!